# Information on values in /proc/pid/task/tid/sched

Tags: linux-kernel, proc, cpu-usage, thread

can someone help me out with the meanings of the following terms in the output of /proc/pid/task/tid/sched?

```
avg_per_cpu 
se.avg.util.sum
se.avg.load.sum
ravg.demand
```

Do any of these values point to the number of CPU cycles a thread goes through?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate what platform your referencing. So I'll answer with to possibilities:

[BSD sched](https://manpage.me/?sched)

[Linux sched](https://manpage.me/?q=sched&manpath=Debian%208.1.0)

Without more information, a simple description is impossible. Other than `man sched`.

HTH

Comment: I am referring to the thread/process info on a Linux system only. I was hoping to get some more information on a few terms I didn't understand in the sched output for individual threads..

Comment: Sure. I understood that. I made a link to the Linux `man` version of `sched` which was pretty detailed, and informative. Did it not cover your question?